# USB HUB on Synology NAS gets disconnected when moving files from one drive to another

Tags: external-hard-drive, nas, hub

I have purchased a USB hub ([Atolla - USB 3.0 Hub with 4 ports](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00W9FLKTY)) to connect several 3.5 in external drives to a Synology NAS ([Synology DiskStation DS118](https://www.synology.com/en-us/products/DS118) single bay NAS), all of them have their own independent power supply. The hub also has a 5V/3A power adapter connected to it.

Everything works fine but when I want to move data from one of the connected drives to another, the hub disconnects and it's like the NAS ejects the drives. I get a warning that I have not ejected the discs safely.

On a Windows PC the hub works perfectly and I can pass data between the drives connected to the hub with no problem. Everything is going perfect, so the problem must be in the nas. Could it be that the power supply of the NAS is not powerful enough to power the hub?

If I connect two external drives directly to the usb drives of the NAS there is no problem, it happens only with the hub.

- HD on hub from NAS to HD PC Windows: OK
- HD on hub from NAS to HD internal disk NAS: OK
- HD on hub from NAS to another HD on hub from NAS: Error and disconnection

Comment: Seems that when copying between drives connected to the hub, the data still has to go in and out from that one single USB 3.0 port and the USB port is being choked/saturated with data. USB 3.0 is 5Gbps which _should_ be the same as USB 3.2 Gen 1 but in my experience chipset compatibility between devices when it comes to USB can choke things. Sadly the only real solution is to try different USB hubs and see what happens. I would recommend this no-name brand USB hub is the choke point. I would recommend getting a better known brand like [this Anker hub](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07L32B9C2/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. But that hub does not have external power, will I not have problems connecting the four external 3.5 drives?

Comment: Not really. The only reason you would need a powered hub is if the drives themselves were only USB powered. If each of the drive ”have their own independent power supply,” the USB hub does not have to be powered. Remember, even USB hubs have their own USB controllers in them and in, as stated before, not all USB hubs are created equally and behave equally when connected to devices.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'll get a brand name hub that is good.

Comment: Sorry this doesn't address your existing equipment... FWIW I've had better throughput using eSATA drive enclosures/ports. It might be worth considering if you decide to upgrade your equipment. Added benefit is that Thunderbolt-to-eSATA adapters will allow you to directly access drives in eSATA enclosures, allowing firmware updates. This is an edge case for many users, though.